# Why not use a rotorcraft drone or quadcopter using GPS navigation to live stream SpaceX booster landings on the droneship?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, gps, droneship

In droneship landings of SpaceX boosters, many times in live streaming, the video has stopped because of vibration in the droneship caused by the 1st stage landing of a Falcon 9 rocket. Would it be possible to film this event with a rotorcraft drone or quadcopter controlled by satellites? I am speaking for [GPS drone navigation](http://www.droneomega.com/gps-drone-navigation-works/) for a GPS drone, or using an autopiloted drone using again the GPS satellite, which would give the command for quadcopter lifting from the SpaceX droneship, moving far enough away to not interrupt the landing process, and returning again to the droneship after the booster's landing. Quadcopters are mostly small and it is easier to land in a small spot.

[Here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-range-of-civilian-drones-UAVs) is a rotorcraft drone that traveled for 2000 km, which is enough for a flight 600 km away from the launch pad of the rocket, where the droneship is stationed, and return back to the launch facility. It could serve as a flyby, but may be difficult to loiter in real time, waiting for the booster landing event.

But I am focussing more on the GPS drone control, and since is more efficient and could be less costly. They have filmed before using manned chase plane (jkavalik comment) which is expensive. Why isn't SpaceX using these kind of drones? Because it is not possible with these GPS drones, because it would cause interference or interrupt the 1st stage controlled landing, or it is something else?

My question is, could they livestream booster landing event in droneship using a drone, and if not, why?

Comment: If the drone should transmit real time using a satellite link, it needs an antenna dish of sufficient size and precisely aimed continously to the satellite. Gusts of wind and the blast of the rocket should not disturb the direction of the camera and the antenna dish.

Comment: @Mark777, note that GPS satellites only transmit a very precise time signal to a receiver. It is the receiver that processes the time signals from several GPS sats, and then calculates location coordinates and altitude. So to control your drone you would need to use another satellite to communicate your control commands and current positional information. You could control a drone via the droneship much more cheaply by retransmission of the satellite signals, than controlling the drone via a satellite based from the launch site.

Comment: @MyOtherHead thanks for information. I didn't have enough info about the way could work the control of drone via sattelites or helped by droneship. Important is that is possible. I have commented geoffc answer, now it remains to prove if crs-8 was filmed by a drone or a manned helicopter. If it is by a helicopter, then remains to now why SpaceX doesn't use drones.

Answer (score 3):

They have done this with a drone, recording a landing before.

[Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glEvogjdEVY) of a drone recording the landing at LZ-1, so on land and thus easier.

[CRS-8 landing on the drone ship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPGUQySBikQ), from a camera drone.

So then the question morphs to, why not do this every time.

Obviously weather will make a difference.  On a stormy day, or at night, flying an expensive drone in bad weather is probably not a great idea. Especially since the benefit is mostly for fans like us. There are cameras on deck recording it and storing it for later.

We do not know that they are not doing this every time and just not releasing the footage.

Comment: I need a clarification. About LZ1 landing is completly a different thing. You could send everyone somewere far away to be safely to record in live streming the landing of course if authorities gives permision. Here it is about the droneship, it is expensive and not practical to send someone to record from a boat or helicopter thats why drone is much more efficient. About crs8 landing i have been thinking that is done frome a helicopter. Could you give a resource that proves this? If you prove, is it like those military helicopter or UAV drones which could be costly to make a flight?

Comment: Hello could you answer what I asked? Could you prove it or not?

Comment: There was a NASA chase plane (not a helicopter - probably too far from the coast for one anyway) during CRS-8 and the linked footage is labeled as [4K footage from chase plane](https://twitter.com/spacex/status/718628506230370308) by SpaceX.

Comment: @jkavalik that chase plane was a drone not a crewed plane monitoring the landing? I wonder what type of chase plane was? If it was a crewed plane or a drone as those used in military, probably are to costly to spend for them just for a live streaming? Sure i gues it should be returned at the coast it couldn't land at the droneship and also we don't now how much cost the trip of chase plane if it is a drone. Still even if it is a drone geoffc answer doesn't answer my question. If it is posible to use a small drone which liftof and land again at the drone ship.

Comment: @Mark777 Please give geoffc some time to reply to your comment.  Not everyone is browsing Stack Exchange 24 hours a day.

Comment: My Other Head says it could work using GPS navigation. If it works why they haven't done or used this method which still remains a question. I am focussing at the combination of small drone with the droneship, because a a long trip of a drone filming and returning to the coast need havy large drones for long range and mabye these are expensive. Smaller drones staying at the droneship are cheaper and more efficient.

Comment: @Phiteros really? I commented again because my comment has more than 3 hours, and geoffc was online 1 hour before at the chat writting about SpaceX, he has seen my comment and could answer about his information. Or he could have written me at chat as he did with DylanSp before, because even me was at chat at the same time. Check the conversation,  that why i wrote again a comment. It doesn't matter still doesn't answer my question were is considered the option for a small drone staying at the droneship.

Comment: @Mark777 you can see what looks like a part of the wing in the [webcast at 29:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_Gmgj3N_Z0&t=29m54s)(T+11:24)

Comment: @Mark777 supposedly [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcWW2UrT9x8&feature=youtu.be&t=8) is [the same](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/4dznx2/crs8_first_stage_landing_on_drone_ship_4k/d1vt2kn/)

Comment: @jkavalik thank you very much for your help and clariffication, so it is a crewed plane not a drone as in geoffc answer. If you find info about my question using a drone to livestream booster landing please write it as an answer.

Comment: @Mark777 I do not have any hard info for an answer. I believe they could use drone if they wanted to - you could station that on the ASDS itself similarly to *Roomba/Optimus Prime* or on the support ship - those few miles should not be a problem for that. I think they just don't need to do it (they get their telemetry and footage anyway). And they are not going to do it just because of the fans watching live.

Comment: The drones can be quite autonomous, performing navigation and recording using GPS and programmed behaviors. It's the radio link that's the problem: good, strong antenna to communicate with distant command center.